# Android Wallpaper onCommand opens apps

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Im trying to setup a live wallpaper and one of the features is when a user taps the screen they will be brought to a specific link, and I noticed that the onCommand method of the wallpaper service engine gets called when I tap on an app icon on the screen. Is there any way I can correct this????

```
@Override
    public Bundle onCommand(String action, int x, int y, int z, Bundle extras, boolean resultRequested) {
        if (action.equals(WallpaperManager.COMMAND_TAP)) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("blalbla");
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.i("Wopps","i do");
            }
        }
        return super.onCommand(action, x, y, z, extras, false);
    }
```

Comment: This is still a problem, it should only be sending the COMMAND_TAP for empty space taps. I logged the issue on the Android tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68467342

Answer (score 0):

So double tap solved the problem :)...onCommand was the wrong approch

```
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(uri);
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("Double tap ", "went wrong");
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```